# Having problems understanding Springboot and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm developing an application with SpringBoot. I already have a RestController and a RabbitMQ component that depending on the message I receive I get some data from a MongoDB and do some logic.

I set up the database as:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collectionName");
```

Since I'm using SpringBoot I wanted to do it with Springboot and acess it in every SpringBoot component (the RestController and the RabbitMQ component).

I already understood that I have to put the settings on application.properties.
What I don't get is how do I acess the database afterwards.
Am I supposed to do a @Configuration class? 
And how can I do, for example, collection.find(eq("id",userID)).first() everywhere?

Comment: are you not planning to use spring data jpa for mongo?

Comment: This is very vast question. You should spend some time on learning the things. There are plenty of material available on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spring data JPA. You literally don't have to write any code.
[Just follow this](https://dzone.com/articles/an-intro-to-spring-boot-with-spring-data-mongo)

Comment: Thanks. Going to try this,